# Jquery makeArray

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this function which works fine except for updating the gallery information... but when i paste the code snippet in the console (chrome developer tool) it works just fine..
Here is what i paste in the console:

```
var obj = $('.item_info'),
arr = $.makeArray(obj);
$(".gallery-info").html(arr[0]);
```

Here is the complete function.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
// If it is the about us page
if($(".page-id-7").length < 1) {
// if it has bullets
    if($(".rsBullets").length) {
        // move the bullets html
        $(".slider_down .pull-right").addClass("rsUni").prepend($(".rsNav"));       
    }
}
// if page has thumbnails
if($(".rsThumbs").length) {
    // get the slider
    var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider');
    // move the thumbnail html
    $(".footer .container-fluid").addClass("rsUni").prepend($(".rsNav"));
    $(".rsNav").toggle();
    // get all divs with the class item-info in an array
    var obj = $('.item_info'),
        arr = $.makeArray(obj);
    // set the gallery-info html to the first item in the array
    $(".gallery-info").html(arr[0]);
    $("#slider_prev").click(function() {
        slider.prev();
    });
    $("#slider_next").click(function() {
        slider.next();
    });
    var curId, totalSlides = slider.numSlides;
    $("#slide_count").html("1 OF "+totalSlides);
    // after slider change
    slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {
        curId = slider.currSlideId + 1;
        // update the count
        $("#slide_count").html(curId+" OF "+totalSlides);
        // update the gallery info to the current item
        $(".gallery-info").html(arr[slider.currSlideId]);
    });
    $(".royalSlider").height("640");
}
}, 0);
```

$(".gallery-info").html(arr[0]); just below this line i tried to alert(arr[0]) which gives undefined.

Also any performance tips will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: What happens exactly, and what should it do? Have you tried using alert() or similar to see in which point the variable has an unexpected content?

Comment: $(".gallery-info").html(arr[0]);
just below this line i tried alert(arr[0]) which is undefined

Comment: try an alert on `$('.item_info').length` to see if it's empty. Why are you using a `setTimeout` with a 0 delay?

Comment: @Jackopo thanks.. alert($('.item_info').length); returns 0 but i know that there are 2 elements with this class..

Comment: I added the timeout function because without it was trying to get slider instance before it was initialized. jQuery fires ready event synchronously to all handlers and as i wanted to fire this instantly i set the timeout to 0

Comment: Hmm, it's difficult to understand what is happening without the HTML. Are these elements already in the page or added through jQuery? If so, it may be a timing problem, and when you use the console the page is fully loaded so you see the element.

Comment: yes i think it is a timing problem.. the item-info is being added by jquery (royal slider)..

Comment: if i try to use another timeout function
setTimeout(function() { 
   var obj = $('.item_info'),
   arr = $.makeArray(obj);
   $(".gallery-info").html(arr[0]);
   return(arr);
}, 500);
it seems to work fine but then how do i use this "arr" outside this function.. returning it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to use another timeout function inside the first one.. not sure if this is the best thing to do but for now it works for me.. i wont make this as the correct answer yet and wait for any better answers.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    var obj = $('.item_info'),
            arr = $.makeArray(obj);
            $(".gallery-info").html(arr[0]);
            slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {
             curId = slider.currSlideId + 1;
                $("#slide_count").html(curId+" OF "+totalSlides);
                $(".gallery-info").html(arr[slider.currSlideId]);
            });
        }, 700);
```